# Excel VBA Cells Value is not returning a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am simply trying to get several values from a range of cells.  It is not returning any value. What am I doing wrong?

I have various numbers in cells B2 to B15.

```
Dim num As String
For n = 5 To 16
    num = Worksheets("Info").Cells(2, n).Value
    Debug.Print num
    Worksheets("Info").Cells(4, n).Value = num
Next n
```

Thanks.

Comment: Switch places on your cell references. The first is the row and the second is the column. `.Cells(n, 2)`

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  Thanks @ScottCraner , that worked.

Comment: We all have those days. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx), the parameters for cell indexes are row then column, *not* column then row. The example on that linked page illustrates this by using `5, 3` for cell `C5`:

> This example sets the font size for cell C5 on Sheet1 to 14 points:
>        `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 3).Font.Size = 14`

Hence your arguments to `Cells` should be `n, 2` and `n, 4` respectively.